# Google Location History shows location I have never been to...6,000 miles away

Tags: google-location-history

I was looking at my GPS location history on my phone, just for fun. When the map loaded, it displayed all of the places I'd been to, *and* a long red line connected to a few red dots in Algeria. Mind you, I am in Texas. At first, I thought it was a glitch. Which I still hope it is. But when I zoomed in with satellite view, the locations were inside a series of neighboring houses. These are very specific locations, and further searches into the previous months (all the way back to December 2014) indicates that these same places have accessed my Google account.

I'm speculating at this point, because I'm not at all familiar with hacking, security, etc. I've also changed my password.

Has this ever happened to anyone? I know that this thing can be inaccurate, but can it be *this* inaccurate? Could Google have made a mistake? Did someone hack into my phone/Google account? Is there a way to confirm this, if the GPS isn't proof enough? And more importantly, if that is the case, what can I do now?

Comment: I'd recommend turning on two factor authentication, if you haven't already. Even if it is a glitch, this step won't do any harm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Location History is showing an incorrect location](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/google-maps-location-history-is-showing-an-incorrect-location)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as that question and its answers are talking about nearby locations.  OP, change your passwords and have all other sessions signed out ("Details" under Last Account Activity at the bottom right of Gmail).