# Location showing inaccurate movements

Tags: applications

Google showing that I left work for almost an hour. It has me located at s nearby restaurant. I never left is this possible? How is thus happening? It shows moving and leave, arrive times. I don't understand. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Location History is showing an incorrect location](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/google-maps-location-history-is-showing-an-incorrect-location)

Answer (score 0):

GPS is by definition not always accurate. If it functions normally, it should give you your position within a radius of 30 metres around you. However, it might malfunction and place you somewhere else.

In addition, your phone uses the list of connected telephone masts to triangulate your position. If GPS was turned off, your location would be found from this. This kind of triangulation is very inaccurate, and changes to your telephone network by the provider could influence it at any point in time.