# Inaccurate location history

Tags: location-services, google-location-history

I have an Motorola moto e, and my location history is inaccurate. Nearly all of my location history is highly  inaccurate. Please help please help

Comment: Might be something useful here; http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/google-maps-location-history-is-showing-an-incorrect-location

Answer (score 1):

Do you have GPS turned on during the day? If not, google locates your position over your phone's network, which is inaccurate. Here are some ways to improve your location history: [find and improve your location's accuracy](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1)