# Do hotels send out wifi signals that place you there?

Tags: wi-fi, geolocation

I need some clear cut answers to a question that gave birth to a divorce after 15 years of marriage. My ex husband's phone( Samsung Galaxy 6) would show him at many questionable places that he says he was not while he was supposed to be "at work". For example it showed him at hotels and he told me he didn't know why it would show that. Then gave me the reply that if you drive by a hotel they send out wifi signals that place you there just by driving by there. Now I have driven by a lot of hotels in our area and they never pinged me at any of them and we had the same GPS location feature. Mine always lined up where I went that day and his would be at all kinds of places.I asked around and no one has ever heard of this and I really want to know is this true???

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WiFi is a major part of location services and is used to locate Android devices. It provides a coarser location fix much more quickly than GPS. It's accuracy is usually ~50m or better, but there are [examples of it not working properly](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/google-maps-location-history-is-showing-an-incorrect-location), so take the entire history into account and not single location fixes.

If you drive by a hotel while you are supposed to be somewhere else and your phone locates itself using the hotel WiFi, you were still at or near the hotel. WiFi signals by design do not travel very far, unless you specifically setup special directional antennas, which definitely do not come with Android phones.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I feel better knowing this information.