# Possible to activate security screen lock only when out-of-home (out-of-specific WIFI )?

Tags: lock-screens

I am quite a critic of every system which does not give a customization abilities. One of them is the frustration of using the security behaviors of phone - specifically, some of use have some of us lock the phone with either Pin-Code or Pattern or Fingerprint or whatever, having phone at home, and unlocking screen hundreds of times a day for no reason, is just out-of-any borders of convenience.

So, i've been thinking, what technical challenges or problems there were, which interfered the developers to implement a relatively easy (not a rocket science) solution, to have "enabled that lock" security mechanism, when we leave home (or specific WiFi) area?  So, at home, we wouldn't need to waste extra ~3 seconds everytime we unlock phone (maybe it's nothing for you, but in sum every day, it is inconvenient for me).

Comment: Check our device for "Smart Lock".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Smart Lock: Why is there no option to use WiFi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181711/android-smart-lock-why-is-there-no-option-to-use-wifi). See all answers