# Google timeline telling me I was somewhere that I wasn't

Tags: google, geolocation, maps

It was a slow day so I just started flicking through my timeline on Google maps to see where I have been ever since I created my Google account. I only have the account on my phone but sometimes sign in on my laptop, these are the only two devices that use my account and I am the only one to have ever accessed my account.

However, when looking at my map I realized that Google said I had been somewhere that I honestly have never been before. It's more than 145 miles away from where I live and I've never been anywhere near this place in all my life. On top of that it also said that I took 16 hours to cross the street in the industrial estate that it placed me in.

I looked in my diary and I'm 100% confident that I wouldn't have left the street where I lived that day. What I don't understand is how this happened?

Answer (score 1):

At the thread [Google Maps Location History is showing an incorrect location](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/google-maps-location-history-is-showing-an-incorrect-location)

Here on Android Enthusiasts, there is an extensive discussion about exactly this problem.

If you’re only looking for a way to edit your timeline, there are some very elaborate instructions at the link [View or edit your timeline](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6258979?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1)

Comment: Thanks :D that helped a lot. I was a little skeptical when I started reading it but it all started to make sense. I guess it's just one of them things that happens sometimes :)