# Google logs my activities wrong

Tags: google-location-history

My Google activities log says I have been messaging people late at night and in the early morning, but I know for a fact I haven't. Plus I have a search on my Google maps I never did. These things are putting a strain on my marriage and I want answers to why this is happening to me. I rarely go anywhere due to me meaning a stay at home mom. I want answers and I want to be able to show my husband that I'm not lying to him about any of this. I'm also getting to were I don't want to do anything on my phone far as searches, texting or making calls.

Comment: For maps showing wrongly see [Google Maps Location History is showing an incorrect location](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44608). For messages etc, please provide more information as also the device used and Android version

Comment: It is showing an incorrect location that I never did search and my husband and I both have seen it. The problem with this is that the place is a road like 20 minutes away from  me and I never look up a road.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar mysterious activity showing up on my account in the past (albeit, several years ago).  It's important to remember that your Google account, and thusly your usage history, can be shared across multiple devices, including a mixture of desktop, laptop, mobile, even TV and assistant enabled devices like Google Home.

I spent a moment going over security and reviewing my account  - it sounds like you would benefit from the same.

First, visit https://myaccount.google.com/

Secondly, sign in to your Google account and you should see some options on the left side pane:

[image: Google myaccount Home]

- Under **Data & personalization**, you can review your privacy settings and also see location history.  Clicking on Location History reveals a page where you can review which devices are contributing to your accounts history.  Be sure to have only the devices you actively use as checked.

[image: review privacy data]

- Under **Security**, I highly recommend turning on 2-step verification.  Also, make sure you have no security issues including any unidentified sign-ins from devices you don't recognize.  You can revoke access to your Google account on a device-basis from this screen.

[image: review security data]

- Under **People and Sharing** you can view who is sharing content with you, including location history.  You can also control which content you see, of course, including location sharing.

In regards to your mobile devices, make sure you audit and remove any suspicious looking apps that you may not remember downloading.

Finally, **reset your Google password**.  This is the single best security practice and often the most overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Your messaging activity is not normal... I'd suggest placing an SMS logger on the device to double check no application is sending messages without your permission, you can find them online ( try searching Parental Control )

I feel that you may be searching for an answer that doesn't exist, are you sure that your location is wrong... For example, You mention that the location is actually near you, this can be two things, The amount of satellites that are deciding the location.. ( On Android, the GPS is not super accurate, it's based on several methods of accumulating location based information to calculate your location - WiFi Device's your near ( connected or not ) - Radio tower your connected to, or multiple towers ( triangulation ) - NFC devices you've passed, that are identifiable by a location ) ... For example, if you passed a Free WiFi Hotspot, your location would be linked to the location of the hotspot owners address )

You will often have an incorrect location ( sometimes up to 100 klm out ) - ( It should say the accuracy of the location based on several algorithms )

So the GPS location might be the radio tower your Android is connecting too, It could also be a WiFi Hotspot that your device is recognizing or it could be your Device hasn't found enough satellites to calculate an accurate location yet ( it usually warms up and calculates the location within 1 meter accuracy at 3seconds - so pay attention if it's GPS based accuracy or Network Location based accuracy ).

As for text messages ... It honestly sounds like you're lying at this point, but it is possible... Some applications can take control of your phone completely through sms commands, the device gets a message and the application hides it from the user, the message tells the app to send back the (eg. call log ) and the app sends a silent message with the information requested by the command SMS ) ... These apps are called SpyWare or MalWare ( Spying & Malicious ) you should open Setting's, Apps, and look through your apps, searching online for each one your unsure about.

P.S Some apps send messages in the background for certain thing's like verifications via SMS etc....