# Could activity showing up on Google My Activity show I used an app but didn't actually use it at that time?

Tags: applications, google

I don't want to accuse my partner of lying if it is possible, for an activity to show up on [Google's My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/) while sleeping or not using the phone.

Is this possible? Or, if it shows up on Google's My Activity, did someone actually have to access the app?

Comment: I think you need to  clarify, phone, model, android version, activity and app.

Comment: I would not recommend answering this question at it's current state as it is too generic and too many details are unknown like what devices exist the account is logged in. It may also have an effect what type of data we are talking about as I don't think Google activity log is precise in all manors. Delays in synchronization may also have an effect on the recorded activities. For a personal history an exact timing is usually not that important but if you want to detect if someone accessed your device...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps Location History is showing an incorrect location](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/google-maps-location-history-is-showing-an-incorrect-location)